# How to repeat a block of code to sample 2 values in r?

Tags: r, loops, statistics-bootstrap, replicate

(I'm new to this so now editing my question as a reproducible example).

I've reviewed bootstrapping,loop and replicate functions and can't figure out how to repeat a series of steps (not just a single function) in R and store the result in dataframe.   I need to randomly select 2 values from a pool of 22 values, 9 times.  Then conduct a spearman rank correlation test on that dataset (2 columns, 9 rows) 10,000 times and store the value of each of those iterations.  So I need to repeat these steps below 10,000 times and store each spearman rank outcome.

```
#For each isotope (C,N,S) obtain two samples of nine individuals extracted
#at random from the pool of the studied population, n = 22 nestlings) and 
#compare their isotopic values with a Spearman rank correlation. 

# take a random sample of size 2 (9 times) from a dataset mysample
# sample without replacement

c13 = c(-25.12, -20.95, -23.98, -23.78,-25.45, -26.27, -11.13, -12.75, -18.77, -18.38, -16.65,
        -16.96, -16.71, -19.57, -20, -23.19, -17.38, -17.83, -18.86, -18.71, -25.57, -21.9)

n15 = c(10.22, 12.64, 11.06, 10.81, 11.55, 11.28, 16.37, 16.17, 13.52, 13.83, 14.27, 14.07, 14.25, 13.09,
        12.59, 11.42, 13.97, 13.77, 14, 15.21, 11.73, 11.8)

s34 =c (4.61, 12.35, 5.19, 5.54, 5.2, 5.12, 14.42, 14.56,
        12.78, 13.11, 18.78, 18.71, 19.19, 11.58, 11.08, 7.89, 17.51, 17.34, 12.55, 12.65, 6.42, 8.49)

df = data.frame(c13,n15,s34)

#c13
mysample <- matrix(sample(c13, 18), ncol=2)
 
#mysample is a vector
is.atomic(mysample)
  
#Convert vector to a dataframe for correlation test.
mysample <- as.data.frame(mysample)
is.atomic(mysample)
 
#name columns
colnames(mysample) <- c ("siblingcarbon1", "siblingcarbon2")
 
#Conduct a Spearman rank correlation test on these randomly selected values 
cor.test(mysample$siblingcarbon1,mysample$siblingcarbon2, method="spearman")
  
# For c13 repeat the prior process 10,000 times and store Spearman rank value for each run (not sure how to do this)
```

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data so we can copy/paste the code into R to run it.

Comment: Isn't that what `mysample` is, @MrFlick? I think what EMC is missing is expected output. (EMC, what have you tried? You can use `replicate(n, { expr; })` or any of `sapply`, `lapply`, `apply`, etc, along with [lists from dataframes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358272). And for the record, a single function is merely a parameterized series of steps ... with other programming benefits such as namespaces, scope, etc.)

Comment: make it a function?

Comment: @r2evans Where does `baea$C13` come from? I can't seem to run that.

Comment: @MrFlick, good point ... I had *assumed* (my bad) valid sample data would work with any set of numbers in place of that, but you are right that EMC should qualify what that set looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the answer based on your edits:

```
c13 = c(-25.12, -20.95, -23.98, -23.78,-25.45, -26.27, -11.13, -12.75, -18.77, -18.38, -16.65, -16.96, -16.71, -19.57, -20, -23.19, -17.38, -17.83, -18.86, -18.71, -25.57, -21.9)
n15 = c(10.22, 12.64, 11.06, 10.81, 11.55, 11.28, 16.37, 16.17, 13.52, 13.83, 14.27, 14.07, 14.25, 13.09, 12.59, 11.42, 13.97, 13.77, 14, 15.21, 11.73, 11.8)
s34 =c (4.61, 12.35, 5.19, 5.54, 5.2, 5.12, 14.42, 14.56, 12.78, 13.11, 18.78, 18.71, 19.19, 11.58, 11.08, 7.89, 17.51, 17.34, 12.55, 12.65, 6.42, 8.49)
df = data.frame(c13,n15,s34)

#create a list to store your results
lst <- list()

#this statement does the repetition (looping)
for(i in 1:1000)
{

  mysample <- matrix(sample(c13, 18), ncol=2)
  #mysample is a vector 
  is.atomic(mysample)
  #Convert vector to a dataframe for correlation test. 
  mysample <- as.data.frame(mysample) 
  is.atomic(mysample)
  #name columns 
  colnames(mysample) <- c ("siblingcarbon1", "siblingcarbon2")
  #Conduct a Spearman rank correlation test on these randomly selected values 
  x <- cor.test(mysample$siblingcarbon1,mysample$siblingcarbon2, method="spearman")
  print(x$estimate)
  lst[i] <- x$estimate
}
str(lst)
```

The results will be stored in the order run in lst.  Ran it 10 times (instead of 1,000):

> str(lst)

```
List of 10
 $ : num -0.5
 $ : num -0.1
 $ : num 0.15
 $ : num -0.8
 $ : num 0.0167
 $ : num -0.617
 $ : num 0.183
 $ : num -0.617
 $ : num 0.2
 $ : num 0.05
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I've updated to include the data and tried the code from PhilC.  After reviewing the lst by str(lst) I still am not clear if it is giving me a list of the correlation coefficients (rho)?

Comment: Please try the updated code above and mark as answered if appropriate.